# Using backspace - CHR(8) - in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ascii

I have a parts management MS Access database. One of the fields is rarely used - it stores whether a part in inventory is actually rare variant of a more common part.  Normally the field is used as a suffix to the primary part number and the database generates that in reports while storing the parent part in the database.  (One primary database which controls part numbers does not contain any information on the variants, but it's important to store because the storefront database does.)

I've found in some cases the variant is *not* simply a suffix. In some cases the correct variant part number eliminates a character from the parent part.  For example part "3069b" has a variant "3069bpb198".  But I found part "30361c" has a variant "30361pb016" which eliminated the "c".

My preferred solution is to encode a backspace character into the field for those variants which require it. Then when i concatenate the parent part number with the variant number, "30361c" & "\bpb016" becomes "30361pb016". However the output I get in my Access query is "30361c□pb016".

The concatenation formulas in the query I've tried are:

```
PartNum: [pl].[PartID] & [variant]  'returns "30361c\bpb016"
PartNum: Replace([pl].[PartID] & [variant],"\b",Chr(8))
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if so what am I doing wrong?

I'd really like to avoid having to change the database so the variant contains the full part number instead of a suffix.

Comment: Replace with empty string, not a backspace character code. Why are you replacing "\b" when you indicate "c" must be removed?

Comment: I don't know that "c" must be removed - just that  the previous character should be removed. \b is a standard escape code for backspace, but it didn't work on its own so I tried replacing it with ASCII backspace (chr(8)).  In reality that c could have been anything

Comment: The query cannot evaluate backspace character into an action. Exactly where do you see the "\b" get evaluated to return "30361pb016"? Have to use string manipulation functions to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you might be able to concatenate the backspace, but how and if that will effect the display of the data is a MASSIVE different issue. The use of ctrl-H goes back to the days of green screens, and even the tele-type age. In other words you want a way to optional remove a character, and using ctrl-H with modern GUI and systems that really don't represent a ASCII character steams means that the question is not about how to make ctrl-H work to chop a char, but how can one chop off a character based  on some kind of information.

In other words ctr-H is a crazy approach unless you using a ASCII green screen, or say a printer.

I also would not introduce a non printable character into that data, since you can't type that information into a field, and worse yet you thus can't search, sort and deal with that column as data.

It gets even worse. Your business rule is that "some" data in one column is to effect the display of another column!!!! This breaks the relational data model so bad, it is not even funny.

What you need is to add a bit column (true/false). In fact, really what needs to occur is the selection of the first column needs to take into account the 2nd column, and a DIFFERNT choice should have been made here.

Now this trick/idea might have worked 25 years ago when most computers were ASCII, working with green screens, and output to a screen/terminal or even for crazy sakes a teletype machine? Well, then ctrl-H would work.

Modern systems are displaying data in a graphical format, and the data is not really ASCII anymore - but is saved in uni-code. (which allows display in just about any language or region).

Now, assuming that the people who suffered some serious brain damage to consider polluting the data this way?

Well, you could use this function:

```
Public Function vScrub(ByVal s As Variant) As String

  Dim c    As Integer

  If IsNull(s) Then
     vScrub = ""
     Exit Function
  Else
     c = InStr(s, Chr(8))
     Do While c <> 0
        s = Left(s, c - 2) & Mid(s, c + 1)
        c = InStr(s, Chr(8))
     Loop
  End If

  vScrub = s

End Function
```

So, place the above in a standard code module (not a class module, nor a forms module).

Once done, then any form, any report, and yes even any query can simply wrap the string expression with above

eg:

```
vScrub([Col1] & [col2])
```

## Edit:

Modify routine to work for multiple chr(8) in the string.

Comment: Agree on the data model. I'm relying on two very large external databases that not only don't agree on part number but don't agree on whether to track variants. And the one without that data is the one I rely on to provide me information about the parts. It's frustrating.  I'll boil your answer down to "create a custom function to handle concatenation" which does seem like the best option. I hadn't really considered ascii vs unicode before.

Comment: I was a bit harsh. You have what you have. I'll admit the idea and concept of using that ctrl-H trick is a VERY interesting trick. One that no doubt bubbled up many years ago by someone with experience using green screen applications based around a text ASCII model. Is it a hack? Sure, it is. Lets all agree on that, but that does NOT mean we all give up and go cry to mommy here. That function as public can be used in any expression - including ones in sql. So if you concatenate several fields with this ctrl-H trick, then wrapping the whole expression in that function will work and off you go!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
PartNum: left([pl].[PartID],len([pl].[PartID])-1) & [variant]
```

Comment: That only works if there is one backspace required and not 0 or 2 or 3. My question though is about whether it's possible to concatenate a backspace into a string in Access